# Ubuntu 12.10 with kernel 3.5.0-18 failing to boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel

I had 12.04 with kernel `3.0.2`. Today I have updated my system and got 12.10 with kernel `3.5.0-18`. Now when I boot my machine with 3.5 kernel, it starts until the page where I enter my password. Within seconds, I get a page with looooong list of some commands or list. I can't take screen-shot of that. It looks something like:

```
[1.2234978942837]kjsahfa;lsfksld;fkjsf;owieurwirejw/rnw;erkjwelrjw2309480432
[1.3294823498230948]as;lfjsf;iuwrijrwjlkerjw;rekwer;lkwjre;lkjRIJWEORIWE'JJA;
```

Luckily, in my boot page, I have 3.0.2 kernel also. When I boot with 3.0.2 kernel there is no problem. But when I boot with 3.5.0, it throws that weird error. I wont be able to do anything at that time. None of the keys work. I have to forcibly shutdown the machine and restart with 3.0.2 kernel.

Please help.

Comment: In situations like this I pull out a camera and snap a picture of the screen :)  Crude but it works and then we can see the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You have a real problem, and it sounds like the system upgrade did not work well on your system. As a temporary solution, you can just uninstall the 3.5.0-18 kernel.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.5.0-18-*
```

As a more permanent solution, you may need to reinstall your system fresh as Ubuntu 12.10. You can keep running the old kernel as long as you want, it won't hurt your system at all, but it will probably keep trying to upgrade.